# DetailView using two ForeignKey kwargs

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-class-based-views, django-1.6

I am trying to utilize Django's class-based generic DetailView by querying the table using two keyword arguments passed via the url. I have tried overriding both the get_queryset() and get_object() method to no avail. My models look like this (edited for brevity, but let me know if something important is missing):

```
# models

class Skill(models.Model):
    skill = models.CharField()

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField()

class UserSkills(models.Model):
    skill = models.ForeignKey(Skill)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, to_field='username')
    value = models.CharField()
```

my url for the DetailView looks like this:

```
url(
    regex=r"^(?P<username>[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,25})/skills/(?P<skill>[a-zA-Z0-9 -._/]+)/$",
    view=views.UserSkillDetail.as_view(),
    name='userskill_detail',
),
```

the view:

```
class UserSkillDetail(DetailView):
    template_name = 'UserSkill_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'skill'
    model = UserSkills

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        get_user = self.kwargs['username']
        get_skill = self.kwargs['skill']
        return get_object_or_404(UserSkills, user__username=get_user, skill__skill=get_skill)
```

I keep receiving the following error via the template debug message:

```
No UserSkills matches the given query.
```

although I am able to successfully query the following via the shell:

```
>>> x = UserSkills.objects.get(user__username='user1', skill__skill='skill1')
>>> x
<UserSkills: user1@example.com: skill1>
```

and have verified that the keyword arguments are being captured correctly ('user1', 'skill1') via the logger and Django debug toolbar. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you print out the values of `get_user` and `get_skill` before the `return` line and see what are those?

Comment: Problem solved: my last migration had failed to call the datamigration as it was out of order. I reconfigured the migration sequence and everything worked. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Consider answering your own question and accept the answer - this would help others in case of similar problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with my migration sequence (called out of intended order). I reconfigured the migrations and everything worked.